# Apache NIFI, rename compressed file without changing the name of the content file

Tags: zip, rename, apache-nifi

I have issues trying to rename a compressed file using the processor CompressContent.

1. I need to rename a flowfile to **content.txt**, then compress it using a different file name (e.g: **compressed.gz**)
2. To accomplish that, I'm using these processors:

   ConvertRecord > UpdateAttribute > CompressContent > UpdateAttribute

   [Flow_diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlIy5.jpg) ,
   [Update_config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hd0E6.jpg) , [Compress_config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tGFT.jpg)
3. But there is a problem, if I rename the compressed file it also affects the name of the txt file (making it unusable).

Is it possible to rename the compressed file without changing the name of the txt file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that mean after all of these you want the content of the `content.txt` file in the flowfile?

Comment: I need the file content.txt compressed with a different name (e.g.: compressed.gz)

Comment: You can use `UpdateAttribute` after that and change the filename. Does this not solve your problem?

Comment: It does not, as the OP says, if I rename the zipped file, for some weird reason it also modifies the name of the content file.